# How to get RGB values per frame from real time video on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, rgb, video-processing

I'm working on making an app using the iPhone. I want to get numerical RGB values from each frame of real time video. Can it be done? If so, please tell me. More appreciate some sample codes. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume that you mean to decode h.264 video and then get the RGB(A) pixel values from it. In that case, you need to use the AVAssetReaderOutput class to open and then decode frames from a h.264 asset attached to the Xcode project. If you are new to video processing in software, be careful and make sure you really understand what you are doing before you begin because memory use in video processing is shocking and you will likely crash your iOS app if you do not fully understand how much memory you are allocating at one time. Please have a look at my blog post on this subject at [video_and_memory_usage_on_ios_devices](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post5_video_and_memory_usage_on_ios_devices/index.html). You can find lots of sample code in bits and pieces all over, but you basically just need to create the asset, decode frames from it, and then read the RGBA pixels from the decoded CoreVideo pixel buffer. Be careful to watch for the case where and odd size results in a row padding in the CoreVideo pixel buffer such that the total number of pixels does not match sizeof(uint32_t) * width * height.